# Display minimum value in a loop vba

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am having an issue to display the minimum value found in my loop. **The goal is to find the the best match possible and display in a message box the company**.

**Issue:** What I do not succeed to do, is to display in a message box the company name for which the difference of the 2 calculation is the minimum. Currently the code displays only the name of the last company.

See picture:

[image]

See the code:

```
Sub BestMatch()

    Dim resultCell      As Double
    Dim checkCell       As Double
    Dim checkCell2       As Double
    Dim bestDiff        As Double
    Dim bestDiff2        As Double
    Dim bestDiff3         As Double

    checkCell = Range("E2").Value
    checkCell2 = Range("E3").Value
    bestDiff = checkCell
    bestDiff2 = checkCell2

    For i = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If (Range("A" & i).Value <= checkCell Or Range("A" & i).Value >= checkCell) And (Range("B" & i).Value <= checkCell2 Or Range("B" & i).Value >= checkCell2) Then

                If (checkCell - Range("A" & i).Value) <= bestDiff Or (checkCell - Range("A" & i).Value) >= bestDiff And (checkCell2 - Range("B" & i).Value) <= bestDiff2 Or (checkCell2 - Range("B" & i).Value) >= bestDiff2 Then

                        bestDiff3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Abs(checkCell - Range("A" & i)) + Abs(checkCell2 - Range("B" & i)))

                        resultCell = Range("C" & i)

                End If
            End If
        Next i

    MsgBox "Best match is in " & resultCell

    End Sub
```

Comment: What does your code do? What did you expect it to do? Is there an error?  Have you located the line of code where it first fails to do what you expect?

Comment: The code works perfectly. Its compute the difference between E2-A1 and E3-B1 (all in absolute value). Then what i do not succeed to do, is to display in a message box the company name for which the difference of the 2 calculation is the minimum. Currently the code display the name of the last company.

Comment: If you store your diffs in an array, use `Application.WOrksheetFunction.Min` to get the minimum difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a conditional statement to compare the `bestDiff3` against (essentially itself) for each loop and check for the smallest one.

I have added that test statement in your code, and also fixed your declaration of resultCell as `Double`, which should be `String` if you expect to return `Company X`.

```
Sub CheckCell()

Dim resultCell As String 'fixed this to return string value of Company X
Dim CheckCell As Double
Dim checkCell2 As Double
Dim bestDiff As Double
Dim bestDiff2 As Double
Dim bestDiff3 As Double
Dim dLowValue As Double 'added as a variable to check for lowest value

CheckCell = Range("E2").Value
checkCell2 = Range("E3").Value
bestDiff = CheckCell
bestDiff2 = checkCell2
dLowValue = 1000 'set to arbitrary beginning number to test against

For i = 1 To Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    If (Range("A" & i).Value <= CheckCell Or Range("A" & i).Value >= CheckCell) And (Range("B" & i).Value <= checkCell2 Or Range("B" & i).Value >= checkCell2) Then

            If (CheckCell - Range("A" & i).Value) <= bestDiff Or (CheckCell - Range("A" & i).Value) >= bestDiff And (checkCell2 - Range("B" & i).Value) <= bestDiff2 Or (checkCell2 - Range("B" & i).Value) >= bestDiff2 Then

                    bestDiff3 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(Abs(CheckCell - Range("A" & i)) + Abs(checkCell2 - Range("B" & i)))


                    If bestDiff3 < dLowValue Then

                        dLowValue = bestDiff3
                        resultCell = Range("C" & i)

                    End If

            End If
        End If
    Next i

MsgBox "Best match is in " & resultCell

End Sub
```